# Find the closest point to the origin

Tags: calculus

**On the line,Find the closest point to the origin**

$y=\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}$

What I did so far is : 
First point is : $(x,\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}})$ and point two is : (0,0)

$d=\sqrt{x^2+(\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}})^2}$

then - > $d' = 2x-\frac{4}{{x^2}}$

I found the X but what then? I do not think I did right.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. First note that $y = \dfrac2{\sqrt{x}}$ is not a line. If $r$ is the distance from the origin, we have
$$r^2 = x^2 + \left(\dfrac2{\sqrt{x}} \right)^2 = x^2 + \dfrac4x$$
Now setting $\dfrac{dr^2}{dx} = 0$, we get that
$$2x - \dfrac4{x^2} = 0 \implies x^* =\sqrt[3]{2}$$
Hence, the value of $r^2$ at the point, which is at minimal distance from the origin is $$r^2 = 2^{2/3} + \dfrac4{2^{1/3}} = 2^{2/3} + 2^{5/3} = 3 \cdot 2^{2/3}$$
Hence, the minimum distance from the origin is
$$r = \sqrt{3} \cdot \sqrt[3]2$$
The point on the cuve is given by $$\left(x^*,\dfrac2{\sqrt{x^*}}\right) = \left(2^{1/3},\dfrac2{\sqrt[2]{2^{1/3}}}\right) = \left(2^{1/3}, 2^{5/6}\right)$$

Comment: so when I found the x - x^3/2 I need to insert in the d/dx and then to get the minimal distance? and what is the point?

Comment: @OfirAttia We get $x = \sqrt[3]{2}$. The point on the curve is $(\sqrt[3]{2},\dfrac2{\sqrt{\sqrt[3]2}})$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $d^2=x^2+\frac 4 x = x^2+ \frac 2 x+\frac 2 x $...

Comment: +1. Very nice! A minor correction. It should be $d^2$, if $d$ stands for the distance.